# Getting an error when defining an alias in the fish shell config file

Tags: shell, fish

I have this alias in my config-fish file:

```
alias em='emacsclient -n -c $PWD&'
```

But I see this error when starting a new terminal:

```
- (line 1): Variables may not be used as commands. In fish, please define a function or use 'eval $argv'.
emacsclient -n -c $PWD& $argv;
                        ^
in function 'em'
    called on standard input
```

What should I do in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing to note is that the fish `alias` command is not the same thing as the bash `alias` command. In fish `alias something` is just shorthand for

```
function something
    something $argv
end
```

In this case I recommend making it an abbreviation: `abbr em 'emacsclient -n -c $PWD&'`. Alternatively define it explicitly using the `function` syntax.